# How to conduct Data Cleaning with Spark-Python based on HDFS

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, pyspark, data-cleaning, data-integration

Currently, I focus on the data preprocessing in the Data Mining Project. To be specific, I want to do the data cleaning with PySpark based on HDFS. I'm very new to those things, so I want to ask how to do that?

For example, there is a table in the HDFS containing the following entries:

```
attrA   attrB   attrC      label
1       a       abc        0
2               abc        0
4       b       abc        1
4       b       abc        1
5       a       abc        0
```

After cleaning all the entries, row 2 `<2, , abc, 0>` should have a default or imputed value for attrB, and row 3 or 3 should be eliminated. So how can I implement that with PySpark?

Comment: What is your question?  What is entry-2 and entry-4?  I read over your question twice and don't know what you're asking.

Comment: @Powers Sorry for the unclarity, is that better now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well on the basis of whatever you asked, there are two things that you want to achieve, first remove duplicate rows which can be achieved by the distinct function

```
df2 = df.distinct().show()
```

will give you the distinct rows of the dataframe.

Second is imputing missing values, which can be achieved by the fillna function

```
df2 = df.na.fill({'attrB': 'm'}).show()
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a very common problem in any data driven solution. The best tool I can recommend for data cleansing with Pyspark is [Optimus](https://hioptimus.com).

So lets see. First lets asume you have this DF in memory already:

`df.show()`

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|attrA|attrB|attrC|label|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|    1|    a|  abc|    0|
|    2|     |  abc|    0|
|    4|    b|  abc|    1|
|    4|    b|  abc|    1|
|    5|    a|  abc|    0|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

To start lets instantiate the DFTransfomer:

`transformer = op.DataFrameTransformer(df)`

1. Set default value for empty cells:

`df_default = transformer.replace_col(search='', change_to='new_value',        columns='attrB').df`

`df_default.show()`

```
+-----+---------+-----+-----+
|attrA|    attrB|attrC|label|
+-----+---------+-----+-----+
|    1|        a|  abc|    0|
|    2|new_value|  abc|    0|
|    4|        b|  abc|    1|
|    4|        b|  abc|    1|
|    5|        a|  abc|    0|
+-----+---------+-----+-----+
```

2. Eliminate duplicate records:

`df_clean = transformer.remove_duplicates(["attrA","attrB"]).df`
`df_clean.show()`

```
 +-----+---------+-----+-----+
 |attrA|    attrB|attrC|label|
 +-----+---------+-----+-----+
 |    4|        b|  abc|    1|
 |    5|        a|  abc|    0|
 |    1|        a|  abc|    0|
 |    2|new_value|  abc|    0|
 +-----+---------+-----+-----+
```